# Getting "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" exception while trying to find duplicate number from an array

Tags: java, arrays

Getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` while trying to find duplicate number in an array in Java.

Here is the code:

```
public class FindDuplicateNumberInArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = { 11, 24, 65, 1, 111, 25, 58, 95, 24, 37 };
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        String sortedArray = Arrays.toString(arr);
        System.out.println(sortedArray);

        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1]) {    
                System.out.println("Duplicate element from teh given array is = " + arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
 at com.onejava.practice.FindDuplicateNumberInArray.main(FindDuplicateNumberInArray.java:19)
[1, 11, 24, 24, 25, 37, 58, 65, 95, 111]
Duplicate element from teh given array is = 24

Comment: `i` will eventually reach the last index in your array, so `arr[i + 1]` will try and access an index outside of your array. Make your loop run to `arr.length-1`, such that the max value `i` will ever get to is the 2nd last index, allowing `arr[i+1]` to be a valid index

Comment: Since you're starting `i` from 1, it would make more sense to compare `arr[i]` with `arr[i-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FindDuplicateNumberInArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = { 11, 24, 65, 1, 111, 25, 58, 95, 24, 37 };
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        String sortedArray = Arrays.toString(arr);
        System.out.println(sortedArray);

        // for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        //    if (arr[i] == arr[i - 1]) {    

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1]) {    
                System.out.println("Duplicate element from the given array is = " + arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To check for a duplicate number, you are running the for loop to last element(say nth position), but your if condition checks the last element with (n+1)th element, which doesn't exist. And also, you need to check the 1st element too, so say i=0.
Or you can just change the if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1]) condition to if (arr[i] == arr[i - 1])

Comment: You're skipping element `0`

Answer (score 0):

You have a very basic `IndexOutOfBounds`-Exception there. When accessing arrays, you have to provide an index. If that index is greater than `array.length - 1`, which is the last accessible index, you get an out of bounds exception. The same is true for lists.

Because you compare the current (`i`) value to the next one (`i + 1`), you run out of bounds, because you count to `i < arr.length`. This means when `i == arr.length - 1` you still add 1 to i, which is equal to arr.length, which is more than arr.length - 1.

Comment: The array is sorted. That's why he's only comparing adjacent elements.